# Rotating text in a table, and getting hlines in the right place

Tags: tables, rotating

I have a table where the first line includes quite some text, and then each of the other cells is fairly small (a symbol or two maximum). At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrr}
  & \begin{rotate}{45}Better measurements\end{rotate} & \begin{rotate}{45}Theory\end{rotate} & \begin{rotate}{45}Intervals\end{rotate} 
  &\begin{rotate}{45} Ensembles\end{rotate} &\begin{rotate}{45}Training\end{rotate} & \begin{rotate}{45}Robustness\end{rotate} 
  & \begin{rotate}{45}Past Success\end{rotate} \\
  Imprecision & x & y & z & a & b & c & x \\
  Inaccuracy & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Deeper & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Parameter & x & y & z & a & b & c&x \\
  Structure & x & y & z & a & b & c &x \\
  Overfitting& x & y & z & a & b & c&x \\
  Discretisation & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Resolution & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Implementation & x & y & z & a & b & c&x \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This uses the `rotating` package for the `turn` environment. The problem is that the `turn` environment does not leave space for the rotated text. (which is good, because the labels "overlap" vertically, which is what I want. However, when I input it in a bigger document the labels overlap the text above. I can just add vspace manually but this is suboptimal. Also, when I try and put `hline`s at the top, they go through the text. (also, it's not great that I have to put the environment in each table cell in the top row)

Are there package that do a better job of dealing with these sorts of tables?

Comment: How about a code sample that is compilable? ;-)

Comment: @lockstep how about you add the three lines yourself

Comment: *Four* lines. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\def\Rot#1#2{\rlap{\rotatebox{#1}{#2}~}}
\begin{document}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabular}{*9l}
  & \Rot{45}{Better measurements} & \Rot{45}{Theory} & \Rot{45}{Intervals} 
  & \Rot{45}{Ensembles} & \Rot{45}{Training} & \Rot{45}{Robustness} & \Rot{45}{Past Success} \\
  Imprecision & x & y & z & a & b & c & x \\
  Inaccuracy & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Deeper & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Parameter & x & y & z & a & b & c&x \\
  Structure & x & y & z & a & b & c &x \\
  Overfitting& x & y & z & a & b & c&x \\
  Discretisation & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Resolution & x & y & z & a & b & c &x\\
  Implementation & x & y & z & a & b & c&x \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Then I haven't understood how your code is working. Could you explain?

Comment: Also, `\hrulefill` doesn't look right if I put a `\hline` at the bottom inside the tabular...

Comment: the `\hrulefill` has _nothing_ to do with the tabular itself ... it shows you the setting of the headers.

Comment: @Herbert exactly. So if I want a `\hline` above my table this method won't work, since it relies on things outside the tabular environment for the spacing.

Comment: @Seamus, again: the `\hrulefill` has nothing to do with the tabular, it shows only that the top of the table headers do not overwrite the current text above the tabular. If you want a `\hline`, then use a `\hline`!!! And if it is too short, then add a dummy column ...

Comment: @Herbert Ah you've edited it again. I hadn't noticed that and was assuming you still had the tabular wrapped in a box. (And I thought that was what made the `\hrulefill` sit above the rotated text)

Comment: `\hline` doesn't extend far enough to the right: it only goes as far as the column of `x`s. Also, I find the spacing looks better if I add a `\hspace{-1em}` just inside the `\rlap`. Other than that, looks great thanks!

Comment: choose another column type or use `\rotatebox` without the `\rlap` for the _last_ column, then it will go over the whole width. But then the bottomrule is too wide ...